# Relative file reference works for Java Script files but not for CSS files

Tags: javascript, css, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ibm-rad

I have a JSP page in a Java EE environment using Rad 8.5 which references CSS and JavaScript files using relative references as shown below.

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MoGem/theme/jquery-ui.css" media="all">

       <script src="/MoGem/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

My issue is the CSS file can't be found while the JavaScript file can be found.  I used a working Java EE project as a template for this project and the set-up looks the same to me but obviously I am missing something.  If you need to see other information let me know.

The error in Firebug looks like this:

[image]

The project file structure is

[image]

The `org.eclipse.wst.common.componet` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
<wb-module deploy-name="MoGem_Web">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/.apt_generated"/>
    <property name="context-root" value="MoGem_Web"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/MoGem_Web/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</wb-module>
```

and the `web.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>MoGem</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>     
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>      
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name> org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml </param-value> 
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Configure Log4j properties</description>
    <display-name>Log4jInitServlet</display-name>
    <icon>
        <small-icon></small-icon>
        <large-icon></large-icon>
    </icon>
    <servlet-name>Log4jInitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gov.mo.dnr.mogem.servlets.Log4jInitServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: aren't you missing the `Web-INF` path? Unless im reading the componet wrong

Comment: I have the ` <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>` and `<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/.apt_generated"/>` lines in the component.  Do I need something else?

Comment: The answer on the question I duplicated solved my problem.  Thanks for pointing it out to me!